Why does this code output order is not as expected by Promise-setTimeout-regular code chain in React
I'm confused by the output of the below code, simply it's like this;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Timeot inner code");
  }, 500);

  promiseInner();

  console.log("Regular inner");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Timeout useEffect");
    }, 500);

    promiseUseEffect();

    console.log("Regular useEffect");
  }, []);

  async function promiseInner() {
    console.log("Promise inner");
  }
  async function promiseUseEffect() {
    console.log("Promise useEffect ");
  }

So one timeout first, then Promise, then a regular code followed by a useEffect. Aware that there is no await before Promises.
The output of above code is;

Which seems kinda weird, I've expected the below output;

Regular inner
Promise inner
Regular useEffect
Promise useEffect
Timeot inner code
Timeout useEffect

Since Promise is a microtask but there is no await, I thought it will be executed after the regular code, but here it is executed before the regular code.
So I'm left with this question and completely have no idea what's going on.

Why the Promises are executed before the regular codes since there
is no await?


Why do you use async without await? Why do you expect regular inner before promise inner? That makes no sense. async functions are synchronously evaluated until the first await. Without await you have synchronous functions that return a promise that immediately resolves to undefined. async function promiseInner() { console.log("Promise inner"); } is function promiseInner() { console.log("Promise inner"); return Promise.resolve(undefined); }

Since async-await is just a syntactic sugar of a Promise, using it without await simply means a Promise without resolving, correct? So, in normal execution, it's first regular code-then promise-then settimeout because the regular code executes before a microtask and a microtask executes before a macrotask, correct? So that's why I expect the regular code executes before the promise.

No, that's not correct. An async function without await is evaluated synchronously. And that's exactly what you can see in the logs. It seems like you don't understand the difference between a promise and a function. A promise is not a function. You can't run or execute a promise. An async function returns a promise. "Since async-await is just a syntactic sugar of a Promise" That makes no sense. async/await are tools to work with promises. They don't replace promises.

I also recommend What is the difference between a function call and function reference?. promiseInner is a function (reference). You can run/execute a function. The function call promiseInner() returns a promise. You can't run or execute a promise. You can await a promise (e.g. that is returned by a function). An async function is not a promise. An async function returns a promise.

The code in an async function is executed synchronously, up until the point it reaches an await. At that point, the function returns a promise. Since promiseInner and promiseUseEffect don't have any await, they do everything synchronously, and the only difference they have from a regular function is that when the function implicitly returns undefined at the end of execution, that undefined gets wrapped in a promise.
If for some reason you want to force the async function to return its promise early and then do the log in a microtask you could do so like this:
async function promiseInner() {
  await undefined;
  console.log("Promise inner");
}

This is not a normal thing to do though.
